# Trigger TouchMove event in Typescript

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine

I am writing some unit tests for an Angular 5 application and have run into an issue trying to trigger a TouchMove event manually. I was able to get this to work for a simulated mouse event using

```
document.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
    clientX: 100
}));
```

but if I try writing

```
document.dispatchEvent(new TouchEvent('touchmove', {
    touches: [{
        clientX: 100
    }]
}));
```

I get an error saying that "Property 'clientY' is missing in type '{ clientX: number; }'", which then changes to other properties of the `Touch` class if I add clientY to my object.

I've also tried creating an instance of `Touch` but the clientX property is read-only. There's an open issue on Typescript's GitHub for this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15874

There is also a `Document.createTouch()` function but this is listed as deprecated on Mozilla's website:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTouch

Is there some better way for me to trigger touch events from a unit test?

Comment: I think [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165209/jasmine-unit-test-that-triggers-mouse-events-in-angular-4) is what you are looking for. Hope it will help.